# jQuery Selecting from String Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm haing a lot of trouble getting this to work.

My server returns a HTML string that displays great, it's all well formed.  When that comes back from the server I do this:

```
var elements = $(data);
var strats = elements.find('.myclass');
```

The string contains `div` objects with a class like:

```
myclass item-container another-class
```

The elements array look like this:

```
0: div.myclass.item-container.another-class
1: text
2: div.myclass.item-container.another-class
3: text
4: div.myclass.item-container.another-class
5: text
6: div.myclass.item-container.another-class
7: text
8: div.myclass.item-container.another-class
length: 9
__proto__: Object[0]
```

But when I try to select just the div objects the array is empty:

```
context: undefined
length: 0
prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[9]
selector: ".myclass"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

I've tried all manner of selectors and I cannot figure it out.  I was under the impression that selectors using just a single class name should work fine.  How do I get just the `divs` with the class `myclass`?

Comment: Is it possible you are searching the elements in the array for div elements as children? A test to find out is to wrap the returned html in a div and then perform the same selector

Comment: question is not clear. Could you add your html code and jqeury code so that I can get a clue

Comment: @Jammer, It's an easy one to miss. :) I spent almost a whole day digging for that same problem a few months ago. Drove me crazy trying to find something to fix it.

Comment: I can imagine!! Pain in the ass!